# Advanced custom field - gallery - display one random image

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I created a gallery with the "gallery add-on" of "advanced custom field" plugin.

I'm trying to show one random image from the gallery on page refresh.
Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $gallery = get_field('gallery_home');           
    $rand = array_rand($gallery, 1);

        if( $rand ): ?>

            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

But the result is this:

```
<img src="" alt="">
```

Where am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this?

```
<img src="<?php echo $rand['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $rand['alt']; ?>" />
```

**Update**

I'm not really familiar with that plugin (stuff could be happening behind the scenes) but here's a better guess than my previous one:

```
<?php
$gallery = get_field('gallery_home');
$rand = array_rand($gallery, 1);

if( $gallery ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $gallery[$rand]['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery[$rand]['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it outputs the same thing. I've a clue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635787/wordpress-display-x-number-of-randomly-selected-images-from-gallery-field but I don't really get it. I'm no good with php.

Comment: If you dump $gallery like this `var_dump($gallery);` – what does it output?

Comment: To see The `var_dump($gallery);` output: http://pastebin.com/a6xFypQQ

Comment: `var_dump($rand);` outputs : `int(n)` where `n` is a number outputted randomly at each page refresh.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: And your answer is working perfectly. Thank you very much.