# ACF Plugin - Random Gallery Image with wp_get_attachment_image()

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, responsive, images

I’ve found others ([source 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99655/advanced-custom-field-gallery-display-one-random-image), [source 2](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/random-image-from-gallery-field/), [source 3](https://gist.github.com/tjhole/8054985)) using the following code for displaying a random gallery image (and it works) with the [ACF Plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/):

```
<?php
$gallery = get_field('images');
$rand = array_rand($gallery, 1);

if( $gallery ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $gallery[$rand]['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery[$rand]['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I’m trying to do it with `wp_get_attachment_image()` (for responsive images) but not sure how to get the `$rand` variable working? The [ACF Documentation for the Gallery field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) has a 'Basic List of Images" example that uses `wp_get_attachment_image()` but I'm not needing to loop through the gallery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think it has to be something like the following, with the `$rand` variable added somewhere:

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('gallery');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $rand = array_rand($images, 1);

    if( $images ): ?>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images['ID'], $size ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found via [ACF Forums](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/random-gallery-image-with-wp_get_attachment_image/). Adding the `false` parameter returns raw/unformatted value.

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('gallery', 'option', false); // Adding the `false` parameter returns raw/unformatted value
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $rand = array_rand($images, 1);

    if( $images ): ?>
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images[$rand], $size ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('gallery');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $rand = array_rand($images, 1);

    if( $images ): ?>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images[$rand]['ID'], $size ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code should work. `array_rand()` return key if second param set to 1 or array with keys if second param > 1

Comment: Thanks. This does work. But I received an answer on the ACF forums (I had posted there first but was not getting any responses, which is why I came to StackExchange) that explained adding a `false` parameter will return raw/unformatted value and therefore does not required ACF having to do all the queries involved to get all that image data that will not be used. I've added this now as an answer (and will accept is as selected answer in 2 days when I can) for anyone looking for this solution in the future.